# Do anyone know how this countdown works? I have been looking into the source code and cant figure out how

Tags: javascript, html, css

Could somone please take a look on this websites sourcecode? http://www.datguylirik.tv/

(Im doing this for testing purpose only)

The problem is that I cant figure out how to get it to work, I have no idea where i "POST" the time it should count down from. Is there some files im missing?

Please take a look on my "copied" website; www.jiggelliee.com

Comment: What do you mean with "I have no idea where I "POST" the time it should count down from." ??? I would suggest using a HTML5 <time> element, somewhere in your code, then would be able to extract the time at which the countdown finishes just by manipulating the DOM.Then, you could write a function that uses setTimeout to update the countdown every second.

Comment: What Im looking to figure out is how he updates his countdown timer, I know there are many ways, but I want to look into this method. Do you have any experience? http://www.datguylirik.tv/js/twitch-utils.js?1401580942

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle I created for you which creates such a countdown timer:

http://jsfiddle.net/kvaKF/

HTML:

```
<div id="countdown-days">
    <h1>0</h1>
</div>
<div id="countdown-hours">
    <h1>0</h1>
</div>
<div id="countdown-minutes">
    <h1>0</h1>
</div>
<div id="countdown-seconds">
    <h1>0</h1>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    var countdown = 0;
    var now = new Date();
    var dateToCountDownTo = new Date(2014, 05, 10); // This is the 10th of june 2014, note that months in JS start at 0!
    var diff = now.getTime() - dateToCountDownTo.getTime()

    var secondDelta = diff / 1000;
    var countdown = Math.floor(Math.abs(secondDelta));


    setInterval(function(){
                        countdown -= 1;

                        var days = Math.floor(countdown / 86400);
                        var hours = Math.floor((countdown % 86400) / 3600);
                        var minutes = Math.floor(((countdown % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
                        var seconds = ((countdown % 86400) % 3600) % 60;

                        $('#countdown-days h1').text(days);
                        $('#countdown-hours h1').text(hours);
                        $('#countdown-minutes h1').text(minutes);
                        $('#countdown-seconds h1').text(seconds);
    }, 1000);
});
```

**Note: It's partly based on the script from the original site you linked to.**

Comment: Thanks alot! Would give you +1 if I had reputation enough!
Got it working now: http://jiggelliee.com/

Did you just create this script? Or did you have it laying around? I would love a way to update it without uploading a new Javascript every time. 

What would be the proper way to do this? I was thinking about making a "Control Panel" Where I can enter the countdown date and update it from there if possible. Im kinda new to this

Comment: Yes it's just something I created just now but I copied some of the countdown code from the original script.  If you want the date to be configurable without updating the JS file everytime, then you'll need some sort of a database on your server and a server side script which allows you to update the date in the database table.  Then you'd need the javascript to call a server side script to read the date from there.  Like you see it's much more complex than what we already have here :-)